# Distribute one big String in different Views React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a big text containing 1500 words, and I want to distribute those words into two different views. If I manually distribute, then it will affect the design of the app due to different device size. Can anyone help me to achieve this result?

**Note**: I don't know which view contains how many words. So I have to distribute the text according to view height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do very simple width checks:

```js
let width = window.innerWidth;
if(width > 300) {
  // Render or truncate text differently
}
```

Comment: How I suppose to distribute the words according to the with and height of the View.you didn't gave me answer of my this question I know how to handle screen width but my point is to distribute the words in different view just like Ms word if user can type extra words it will automatically change the page and set the sentences according to it

Comment: @HarisShahid this isn't really enough information to help you, if you could add some more detail or your current code. Not exactly sure what the problem is.